# How do I get rid of this extra section below the footer - Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

Underneath my footer on the webpage I'm working on, there seems to be an extra section (almost another div which is the blue area) which appears beneath it. Any guidance on how to get rid of it and which code even included it?

[image: Screenshot of extra section I don't want in blue (under the green footer)]

1st Section of code is from the signup.php page:

```
<body>
    <main>
      <div class="wrapper-main">
        <section class="section-default">
          <h1 class="h1-signup-title">Signup</h1>
          <?php
          // Here we create an error message if the user made an error trying to sign up.
          if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
            if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyfields") {
              echo '<p class="signuperror">Fill in all fields!</p>';
            }
            else if ($_GET["error"] == "invaliduidmail") {
              echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username and email!</p>';
            }
            else if ($_GET["error"] == "invaliduid") {
              echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username!</p>';
            }
            else if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidmail") {
              echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid email!</p>';
            }
            else if ($_GET["error"] == "passwordcheck") {
              echo '<p class="signuperror">Your passwords do not match!</p>';
            }
            else if ($_GET["error"] == "usertaken") {
              echo '<p class="signuperror">Username is already taken!</p>';
            }
          }
          // Here we create a success message if the new user was created.
          else if (isset($_GET["signup"])) {
            if ($_GET["signup"] == "success") {
              echo '<p class="signupsuccess">Signup successful!</p>';
            }
          }
          ?>
          <form class="form-signup" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
            <?php
            // Here we check if the user already tried submitting data.

            // We check username.
            if (!empty($_GET["uid"])) {
              echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username" value="'.$_GET["uid"].'">';
            }
            else {
              echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">';
            }

            // We check e-mail.
            if (!empty($_GET["mail"])) {
              echo '<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email" value="'.$_GET["mail"].'">';
            }
            else {
              echo '<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email">';
            }
            ?>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password">
            <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
          </form>



          <!--Here we create the form which starts the password recovery process!-->
          <?php
          if (isset($_GET["newpwd"])) {
            if ($_GET["newpwd"] == "passwordupdated") {
              echo '<p class="signupsuccess">Your password has been reset!</p>';
            }
          }
          ?>

          <a class="p-forgetpwd" href="reset-password.php">Forgot your password?</a>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>


</body>
</html>


<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

The 2nd section of code is from the footer.php code:

```
<hr class="my-0 border-white">
<footer class="site-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
    <section class="social-links py-3 text-center">
        <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://twitter.com" class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://www.pinterest.co.uk" class="fa fa-pinterest" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://www.instagram.com" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <span> &copy; iStudy 2018</span>
    </section>
</footer>
```

UPDATE: The CSS that links with the signup.php page code:

```
.wrapper-main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-default {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.h1-signup-title { /* For the signup form page */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: black;
}

.form-signup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.form-signup input {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  float: left;
  font-family: arial;
}

.form-signup button {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper-main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate this in a snippet that we can run?

Comment: Are you talking about the blue section on the bottom?

Comment: You will want to include the basic snippet with any additional non bootstrap4 CSS that you may have. As that spacing could be as simple as not enough content to push down the footer.

Comment: @imvain2 I think you nailed it, the background is probably set to that blue-ish color on the `<main>` or `<body>` tags and there isnt enough content to push the footer down to the bottom.

Comment: Yes @Ice76 .
Thank you all so much for your comments, so the <body> tag only had some colour settings applied, no padding. However I found <main> tag with some styling applied. This is what happens when you try and follow a YouTube tutorial, then style yourself.

Comment: I did add 2 x  <br> tags which did move it down, is this not best practise to use break lines to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you will want to force your footer to the bottom. This will always keep your footer at the bottom your website no matter how much content you have on the page. Please note you will need to figure out and type in how tall your footer is.

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @imvain2, I have tried this and it does push it down however it just increases the actual size of the footer, so I set the height to 180px; which got it up to  where it needed to be but it just looked very tall for a footer, it does definitely work though so thank you. I'll have a little play around.